# Add text to the first line of a file with puppet

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to add a single line (or better yet a few lines) of new text to the very first line of a file with Puppet? (and have it do it just once obviously)

The background is, I am managing certain lines in the file, but I would like to put a one-time comment at the top of the file so its clear parts of this file are "managed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with standard puppet resources such as file_line or augeas. What you could do is use an exec fx [**edited**]:

```
$file = /somefile,
$text = 'some text'
) {
  exec { "add ${text} to ${file}":
    command => "sed -i '1s/^/${text}\\n/' '${file}'",
    unless  => "grep '${text}' '${file}'",
    path     => ['/bin'],
  }    
}
```

See [How do I add text to the beginning of a file in Bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash#246841) for other examples using bash.

[**original posted syntax**]
The example is updated with suggesting from [anonymous] to support spaces in filename and double escaped new line. Kept original syntax below for reference, since I haven't tested the double escaping of newline.

```
$file = /somefile,
$text = 'some text'
) {
  exec { "add ${text} to ${file}":
    command => "sed -i '1s/^/${text}\n/' ${file}",
    unless  => "grep '${text}' ${file}",
    path     => ['bin'],
  }    
}
```

Comment: Yea, it appears it can't be done natively with puppet but this is a nice compromise! Thanks for the answer with example and links to more!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `concat` module, which works quite well. Basically, you declare the file and you use `concat::fragment` to create the file with the new content and the original. I also used a custom fact to get the original text of the file to be able to concatenate both:

```
concat { '/somefile':
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode  => '0644'
}

concat::fragment { '/somefile':
  target  => '/somefile',
  content => 'This is new text\n',
  order   => '01'
}

concat::fragment { '/somefile':
  target  => '/somefile',
  content => $facts['original_text'],
  order   => '02'
}
```

To create the custom fact:

```
Facter.add('original_text') do
  confine kernel: 'Linux'
  setcode do
    Facter::Core::Execution.execute('cat /somefile')
  end
end
```

This is simplified answer that doesn't include finding the original user of the file and checking if `/somefile` exists and if the new text is already in the file.